# How to use a Type as an Expression?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, types, controls

I was wondering if exist a trick to use a Type as an expression, for example in this code:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim ControlType = CheckBox ' CheckBox is a type and cannot be used as an expression

    Dim ControlArray(5) As ControlType ' (5) The number of controls to create.

    For num As Int64 = 0 To ControlArray.LongLength - 1
        ControlArray(num) = New ControlType ' Expected: New CheckBox
        ControlArray(num).Text = (ControlType.ToString & num.ToString) ' Expected string: "CheckBox 0"
        Me.Controls.Add(ControlArray(num))
    Next

End Sub
```

I'm not asking how I can do a control array, I'm asking if I can do a generic control array for example expecifying the Type in a var (ControlType) and using it like in the code example above.

> UPDATE

This is now the code I'm trying to use

I can't recognize the "CheckedChanged" event of the CheckBox when trying to attach the handler

Also can't recognize the ".Checked" property when trying to check the value of it.

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim ControlType As Type = GetType(CheckBox) ' The type of Control to create.
    Dim ControlArray(5) As Control              ' (5) The number of controls to create.

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        For num As Int64 = 0 To ControlArray.LongLength - 1
            ControlArray(num) = Activator.CreateInstance(ControlType) ' Create the control instance (New CheckBox)
            ControlArray(num).Name = ControlType.Name & num.ToString ' Name example  : CheckBox 0
            ControlArray(num).Text = ControlType.Name & num.ToString ' String example: CheckBox 0
            ControlArray(num).Top = 20 * num ' Adjust the location of each control.
            Me.Controls.Add(ControlArray(num)) ' Add the control to a container.

            ' This does not work:
            AddHandler ControlArray(num).CheckedChanged, AddressOf CheckBoxSub ' Add a event handler to a procedure.

        Next

    End Sub

    Public Sub CheckBoxSub(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) ' Sub which is handling the controls.

        If sender.Checked = True Then MsgBox(sender.name & " is checked") Else MsgBox(sender.name & " is unchecked")

        ' Just an example of how to use the controls,
        ' This does not work:
        ControlArray(2).checked = True ' CheckBox 2.Checked = True

    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use System.Type to hold the type of an object.

You can also use Activator.CreateInstance(MyType) to create a instance of the object of type MyType.

e.g.

```
Dim ControlType As System.Type = GetType(CheckBox)
Dim ControlArray(5) As Control

For num As Int64 = 0 To 5
    ControlArray(num) = Activator.CreateInstance(ControlType)
    ControlArray(num).Left = num * 100
    ControlArray(num).Name = "CheckBox " & num
    ControlArray(num).Text = ControlArray(num).Name
    Me.Controls.Add(ControlArray(num))
Next
```

EDIT:

To add an event handler, you would need to DirectCast() the Control to the object type, e.g.:

```
AddHandler DirectCast(ControlArray(Num), CheckBox).CheckedChanged, AddressOf MyHandler
```

Comment: Thankyou so much, but I'm having problems trying to add a handler using your modification, can you see my updated question please?

Answer (score 1):

About your updated question: You need to *cast* the object to the correct type to be able to use CheckBox-specific properties or events. E.g. instead of

```
AddHandler ControlArray(num).CheckedChanged, AddressOf CheckBoxSub
```

you write

```
Dim cbx As CheckBox = TryCast(ControlArray(num), CheckBox)
If cbx IsNot Nothing Then
    AddHandler cbx.CheckedChanged, AddressOf CheckBoxSub
End If
```

Same for your second example:

```
Dim cbx As CheckBox = TryCast(ControlArray(2), CheckBox)
If cbx IsNot Nothing Then         ' If the second control is a check box 
   cbx.Checked = True 
End If
```

`TryCast` casts the given object to the given type or returns `Nothing` if the object has a different type.